# Is there a way to update the attribute table of a feature class with a query?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, sql

I have a layer with multi-polygon feature classes for states and provinces. The shape area for some features classes is < 0 causing the label to be position in odd locations. It seems that the calculation is generally correct, and that if I could update all shape area in a single query I could fix this quickly. Currently I am querying to identify the negative area features classes, and editing a point, which resets the area and then it labels correctly. However it would be much quicker to be able to run a batch update on the value.

Comment: How was this data created? Data created with Esri tools shouldn't produce features with an area < 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I've seen negative values in the Shape_Area field is when a polygon's vertices are ordered incorrectly. [Repair geometry fixes ring ordering](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000.htm), which fixes the problem with Shape_Area.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Calculate Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000027000000.htm) on a field, and calculate the area.

If the data is stored in a geodatabase, this field is added and updated automatically.